# In React i'm getting this.setState is not a function error within setTimeout/setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I've seen a few topics on the issue 'this.setState is not a function', but none have fixed it for me. I've used arrow functions or binding 'this', but still getting the error. The initial attempt is below. It uses nested setTimeout functions (i can explain why if it would help), but the issue is around this.setState.

Without looking into the 'useEffect' Hook, could i check whether i'm missing something basic/fundamental to setting state in React in the code below?

```
let delay = 5000;
      var startTime = new Date().getTime();

      let intervalTimerId = setTimeout(function request() {

        // first apply a random number to a div
        let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        // document.querySelectorAll(".someClass"+randomNum)[0].setAttribute("id", "test");

        // then after a second, remove the class
        setTimeout(() => {
          // document.querySelectorAll(".someClass"+randomNum)[0].setAttribute("id", "");

          // after another second, set state to use later
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({someState: "testing"});
          }, 1000)

        }, 1000)

        // set new delay time
        if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 9000) {
          delay = 3000;
        }

        console.log(new Date().getTime() - startTime)

        intervalTimerId = setTimeout(request, delay);

      }, delay);
```

Comment: are you writing this with class component or with hooks?

Comment: class component (class TestApp extends Component {)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use arrow function

```js
let delay = 5000;
var startTime = new Date().getTime();

const request = () => {
  // first apply a random number to a div
  let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  // document.querySelectorAll(".someClass"+randomNum)[0].setAttribute("id", "test");

  // then after a second, remove the class
  setTimeout(() => {
    // document.querySelectorAll(".someClass"+randomNum)[0].setAttribute("id", "");

    // after another second, set state to use later
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ someState: 'testing' });
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);

  // set new delay time
  if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 9000) {
    delay = 3000;
  }

  console.log(new Date().getTime() - startTime);

  intervalTimerId = setTimeout(request, delay);
};

let intervalTimerId = setTimeout(request, delay);
```

Comment: thank you @baymax this looks to have solved it. i had previously used an arrow function at the top, but not declared it as a 'const'. maybe the issue was around that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use bind:

```
let intervalTimerId = setTimeout(function request() { ... }.bind(this)
```

Assuming that you are using a class component and that `this` is not already broken, one of the [motivations](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#motivation) not to use class components:

> In addition to making code reuse and code organization more difficult, we’ve found that classes can be a large barrier to learning React. You have to understand how this works in JavaScript, which is very different from how it works in most languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can either bind this explicitly with `.bind(this)` or simply replace function syntax with the arrow function, as `this` within arrow function is equal to the outer `this` where the function is declared:

```
let intervalTimerId = setTimeout(() => {
    ...
    setTimeout(() => {
       this.setState({someState: "testing"});
    }, 1000)
}, delay);
```